# react-native: Animate position of Animated.View during onPanMove

Tags: react-native

I have set up an animation and want to animate a View, so when the user touch moves the view follows on the y axis.

I have tried to set this up with Animated.event but it doesn't work. Can somebody please explain how Animated.event works in a panResponder?

This is what I have:

```
const onPanMove = (evt: GestureResponderEvent, state: PanResponderGestureState) => {
    Animated.event([null, {dy: new Animated.Value(state.dy)}], {useNativeDriver: true});
};
```

But nothing happens. I also googled a lot, but didn't find any good documentation on this.

When I replace the `event` with `timing` it works, but it's super laggy since it always waits for the touchmove to pause.

```
Animated.timing(
    this.state.position,
    {
        toValue: startY - state.dy,
        duration: 0,
        //easing: this.props.easing,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }
).start();
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm under the same situation :(